# python win32service - Getting triggered startup information for service

Tags: python, winapi, triggers, startup, pywin32

win32 API [QueryServiceConfig2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988(v=vs.85).aspx) function supports the SERVICE_CONFIG_TRIGGER_INFO structure to get event(s) that trigger the service startup. However, python's [win32service.QueryServiceConfig2()](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32service__QueryServiceConfig2_meth.html) does not list such value as a parameter option. Is it possible to get that information with the win32service module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Here's a simple code snippet ran under *Python 3.5* and *PyWin32 v221*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import win32service


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for name in dir(win32service):
        if name.startswith("SERVICE_CONFIG_"):
            print(name, getattr(win32service, name))
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q046916726>"c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" a.py
> SERVICE_CONFIG_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO 3
> SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION 1
> SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS 2
> SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS_FLAG 4
> SERVICE_CONFIG_PRESHUTDOWN_INFO 7
> SERVICE_CONFIG_REQUIRED_PRIVILEGES_INFO 6
> SERVICE_CONFIG_SERVICE_SID_INFO 5
> ```

I've also checked *win32con* (which is another *PyWin32* module, that only contains constant definitions), but no luck either.

Then, I took a look at *${PYWIN32_SRC_DIR}/pywin32-221/win32/src/win32service.i*, and noticed that for *ChangeServiceConfig**2*** (and also *QueryServiceConfig**2***), the *InfoLevel* argument is specifically checked against the above constants, and thus passing its value (**8**) directly, would raise an exception (*NotImplementedError*).

Before going further, let's spend a little bit understanding what happens when calling such a *Python* wrapper (like `win32service.QueryServiceConfig2`):

1. Arguments (*Python* style - if any) are converted to *C* style
2. *C* function is called with the above converted arguments
3. Function result (or output arguments) - if any - are converted back to *Python*

For [[MS.Docs]: ChangeServiceConfig2W function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-changeserviceconfig2w), data is transferred back and forth via arguments (depending on *dwInfoLevel* value, *lpInfo* can have various meanings):

- Let's take a look to a value that is supported: e.g. *SERVICE_CONFIG_PRESHUTDOWN_INFO*:

  - *lpInfo* is a pointer to a [[MS.Docs]: SERVICE_PRESHUTDOWN_INFO structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-_service_preshutdown_info) which only has a *dwPreshutdownTimeout* member (which is a simple *DWORD*)
- On the other hand, *SERVICE_CONFIG_TRIGGER_INFO*:

  - *lpInfo* is a pointer to a [[MS.Docs]: SERVICE_TRIGGER_INFO structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-_service_trigger_info)

    - *pTriggers* member is a pointer to a [[MS.Docs]: SERVICE_TRIGGER structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-_service_trigger)

      - *pDataItems* member is a pointer to a [[MS.Docs]: SERVICE_TRIGGER_SPECIFIC_DATA_ITEM structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-_service_trigger_specific_data_item)

  which is waaay more complex (and note that all involved structures have other members as well, I only listed the ones that increase the nesting level).

Adding support for all those arguments is not exactly a trivial task, so they aren't handled (at least for the moment).

There are more examples like this one, I guess it's a matter of priority, as not many people requested the functionality, combined with *MS*'s (unfortunate?) design decision to have functions with such complex behaviors.

As an alternative (a quite complex one), you can use [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), but you'll have to define all the structures that I listed above in *Python* (to extend `ctypes.Structure`).

- As a side note, I was in the exact situation once: I had to call [[MS.Docs]: LsaLogonUser function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsalogonuser) (**!!! 14 freaking arguments !!!**). Obviously, it wasn't exported by *PyWin32*, so I called it via *ctypes*, but I had to write:

  - ***~170*** lines of code to define structures (only the ones that I needed for my scenario)
  - ***~50*** lines to populate them and call the function